# No wifi and bluetooth on Debian laptop

Tags: wireless-networking, debian, bluetooth

So I recently installed Debian on my laptop, and since then I have not been able to connect to any wifi networks, or bluetooth devices. There simply is no option for wireless in the "network" setings.

Some quick google search led me to install the missing "firmware" which I did; but still, there has been no change.

What exactly am I supposed to do?

EDIT:
I did lspci to check my wifi driver and here is here is the result:

```
lspci -vv -s 03:00.0

03:00.0 Network controller: Broadcom Limited BCM43142 802.11b/g/n (rev 01)
Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company BCM43142 802.11b/g/n
Control: I/O- Mem+ BusMaster- SpecCycle- MemWINV- VGASnoop- ParErr-  Stepping- SERR- FastB2B- DisINTx-
Status: Cap+ 66MHz- UDF- FastB2B- ParErr- DEVSEL=fast >TAbort- <TAbort-  <MAbort- >SERR- <PERR- INTx-
Interrupt: pin A routed to IRQ 255
Region 0: Memory at b0500000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=32K]
Capabilities: <access denied>
```

I am using Gnome desktop environment.

Comment: Can you see the device if you enter `lspci` or `lsusb` command?

Comment: Are you looking for a GUI interface, like a system tray icon or something in system settings, or are you trying to access it through the terminal?  What desktop environment are you using?

Comment: @fixer1234 I have tried both the ways to connect. I just need to somehow connect to any wireless device, terminal or GUI does not matter. My laptop seems to not know the existence of wireless options.

Comment: It's common for WiFi drivers to be proprietary.  Debian doesn't include any of that by default because they're sticklers about open source.  Search for the driver (check Broadcom's web site to identify it).  You will probably need to add Debian's non-free repository ([How do I enable non-free packages on Debian?](https://serverfault.com/q/240920)).  Check that to see if they have it.  Adding the repository will allow the package manager to maintain it if you can install it from there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [Debian wiki](https://wiki.debian.org/wl#Installation):

1. Add `non-free` to an existing package source of your `/etc/apt/sources.list`.

   Example:

   ```
   deb http://httpredir.debian.org/debian/ stretch main contrib non-free
   ```
2. Install the latest kernel, kernel-headers and `broadcom-sta-dkms` package:

   ```
   apt-get update
   apt-get install linux-image-$(uname -r|sed 's,[^-]*-[^-]*-,,') linux-headers-$(uname -r|sed 's,[^-]*-[^-]*-,,') broadcom-sta-dkms
   ```
3. Unload conflicting modules:

   ```
   modprobe -r b44 b43 b43legacy ssb brcmsmac bcma
   ```
4. Load the `wl` module:

   ```
   modprobe wl
   ```

If missing, [install the gnome network manager](https://wiki.debian.org/WiFi/HowToUse#GNOME)

```
apt-get install network-manager-gnome
```

then logout and login again. A new applet (computer icon) will appear in the notification area / system tray.

**EDIT:**

I can sadly confirm that `broadcom-sta-dkms` fails to compile on kernel 4.19.0-0.bpo.4-amd64:

```
me@meme:~# apt-get install linux-image-$(uname -r|sed 's,[^-]*-[^-]*-,,') linux-headers-$(uname -r|sed 's,[^-]*-[^-]*-,,') broadcom-sta-dkms
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
linux-headers-amd64 is already the newest version (4.19+104~bpo9+1).
linux-image-amd64 is already the newest version (4.19+104~bpo9+1).
The following package was automatically installed and is no longer required:
  xaw3dg
Use 'apt autoremove' to remove it.
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  broadcom-sta-dkms
0 upgraded, 1 newly installed, 0 to remove and 86 not upgraded.
Need to get 2,211 kB of archives.
After this operation, 14.5 MB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
Get:1 http://ftp.de.debian.org/debian stretch/non-free amd64 broadcom-sta-dkms all 6.30.223.271-5 [2,211 kB]
Fetched 2,211 kB in 6s (357 kB/s)                                                                                                 
Selecting previously unselected package broadcom-sta-dkms.
(Reading database ... 181313 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../broadcom-sta-dkms_6.30.223.271-5_all.deb ...
Unpacking broadcom-sta-dkms (6.30.223.271-5) ...
Setting up broadcom-sta-dkms (6.30.223.271-5) ...
Loading new broadcom-sta-6.30.223.271 DKMS files...
Building for 4.19.0-0.bpo.4-amd64
Building initial module for 4.19.0-0.bpo.4-amd64
Error! Bad return status for module build on kernel: 4.19.0-0.bpo.4-amd64 (x86_64)
Consult /var/lib/dkms/broadcom-sta/6.30.223.271/build/make.log for more information.
```

However it does compile on kernel 4.4.0.

**EDIT2:**

Instructions how to install the newest version of `broadcom-sta-dkms` from the Debian backports repository:

1. Remove non-working `broadcom-sta-dkms`

   ```
   apt-get remove broadcom-sta-dkms
   ```
2. Add a repository entry for stretch-backports in `/etc/apt/sources.list`

   ```
   echo "deb http://ftp.debian.org/debian stretch-backports main contrib non-free" >> /etc/apt/sources.list
   ```
3. Update package index and install `broadcom-sta-dkms` from the backports repository

   ```
   apt-get update
   apt-get -t stretch-backports install broadcom-sta-dkms
   ```

Comment: So I did all of that, and at the last step, when I'm loading the wl module, this happens:

modprobe: FATAL: Module wl not found in directory /lib/modules/4.9.0-8-amd64

Comment: Yep, see my EDIT. It seems something changed in newer kernels which prevents a clean compile. It builds on 4.4.0, but not on 4.19. See this [bug report](https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=899351). You can [install the latest kernel](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/508666/332764) from the backports repository 
and try again with `apt-get remove broadcom-sta-dkms; apt-get -t stretch-backports install broadcom-sta-dkms`. But I can't tell if this will work...

Comment: Forgot to mention: You need to add `non-free` to the backports sources like `deb http://ftp.debian.org/debian stretch-backports main contrib non-free`, otherwise apt will fetch the same version.

Comment: So I did all of that once again, and even if it still shows the FATAL error, it is now actually connecting to both bluetooth and wifi devices. I don't really know what worked. Thanks a lot!